# virgo tomcat server runs on 3.1.0.release of spring my web app depends on 3.2.0. how do i resolve this?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc, eclipse-virgo

I want to migrate my web app from standard war to WAB using Virgo Tomcat Server.
The std war file depends on spring 3.2.0.RELEASE and VTS has 3.1.0.RELEASE. 
I tried to deploy all the spring 3.2.0 jars and my web app specific jars in usr directory of virgo.
And when i try to deploy the war in pickup folder with import to 3.2.0 spring release, there is a version conflict between the 3.1.0 and 3.2.0 releases.

Will the highest available version  of jar from the specified range not be picked up?

ex., there are 2 jars 
1. spring-core version 3.1.0.RELEASE
2. spring-core version 3.2.0.RELEASE

And the manifest has an import saying
org.springframework.core;version="[3,4)"

shouldnt it pick up 3.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

The [VTS FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/FAQ) explains how to upgrade the version of Spring used by webapps:

- [How can I change the version of Spring framework in the user region?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/FAQ#How_can_I_change_the_version_of_Spring_framework_in_the_user_region.3F)

I'm not entirely sure I understand everything that it is saying, but it does say that Spring 3.2 is supported in Virgo 3.6.0.  Also, it seems to be saying that the upgrade doesn't happen auto-magically by some version selection mechanism.  You apparently have to delete the old JARs.